# Listen for new signal connections on a pyqtBoundSignal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I have a PyQt5 application that has optional functionality (let's say a button) that only shows up when the application is explicitly told "Turn on this option." When this button is invoked, the application works some computation and then emits a signal with the result.

Instead of having to explicitly pass a constructor option, I would like the program to display the functionality when someone connects to the signal.

**Working Example**:

```
class ExampleApp(QWidget):
    do_something = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, something_enabled: bool = False):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Do something")
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.do_work)

        self.button.setVisible(something_enabled)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def do_work(self):
        self.do_something.emit("Something!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp(something_enabled=True)
    window.do_something.connect(lambda result: print(result))
    app.exec()
```

I could not find any available options in the docs, and I have not been able to find an implementation of this functionality. In my own code, I tried directly changing the connect function, but I get a read-only AttributeError.

**Wrapper Function**:

```
self.original_connect = self.do_something.connect

def new_connect(slot, type=None, no_receiver_check=False):
    print("New connection!")
    self.original_connect(slot, type, no_receiver_check)

self.do_something.connect = new_connect
```

**AttributeError**:

```
AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' object attribute 'connect' is read-only
```

I also created a working wrapper class, but I am wary of unknown consequences.

**Wrapper Class**:

```
class SignalWrapper(QObject):

    new_connection = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, signal_to_wrap):
        super().__init__()
        self.wrapped_signal = signal_to_wrap
        self.signal = self.wrapped_signal.signal

    def connect(self, slot, type=None, no_receiver_check=False):
        self.new_connection.emit(slot)
        return self.wrapped_signal.connect(slot)

    def disconnect(self, slot=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        return self.wrapped_signal.disconnect(slot)

    def emit(self, *args): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        return self.wrapped_signal.emit(*args)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        return self.wrapped_signal.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        return self.wrapped_signal.__getitem__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        return self.wrapped_signal.__repr__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Modified Portion of ExampleApp**:

```
class ExampleApp(QWidget):
    do_something = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.do_something = SignalWrapper(self.do_something)
```

I would like to know if there is a graceful way to intercept signal connections in PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QObject` class has virtual [connectNotify](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connectNotify) and [disconnectNotify](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnectNotify) methods which can be overidden to provide different behaviour. The default implementations do nothing. There is also a [receivers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#receivers) method which gives the current connection count for a signal.

The demo below uses these methods to create a generic connection watcher class that can be attached to any `QObject` subclass. It monitors a group of signals and emits a `connected` signal whenever it detects an initial connection or a final disconnection:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ConnectionWatcher(QObject):
    connected = pyqtSignal(str, bool)

    def __init__(self, target, *signals):
        if not target.findChild(ConnectionWatcher):
            super().__init__(target)
            self._signals = set(signals)
            target.connectNotify = lambda s: self._notified(s, True)
            target.disconnectNotify = lambda s: self._notified(s, False)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('target already has a connection watcher')

    def _notified(self, signal, connecting):
        name = str(signal.name(), 'utf-8')
        if name in self._signals:
            count = self.parent().receivers(getattr(self.parent(), name))
            if connecting and count == 1:
                self.connected.emit(name, True)
            elif not connecting and count == 0:
                self.connected.emit(name, False)

class ExampleApp(QWidget):
    do_something = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, something_enabled: bool = False):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Do something")

        watcher = ConnectionWatcher(self.button, 'pressed')
        watcher.connected.connect(self.handleConnection)

        c1 = self.button.pressed.connect(self.do_work)
        c2 = self.button.pressed.connect(self.do_work)

        self.button.pressed.disconnect(c1)
        self.button.pressed.disconnect(c2)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def handleConnection(self, name, connecting):
        print('connecting:', name, connecting)

    def do_work(self):
        self.do_something.emit("Something!")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp(something_enabled=True)
    window.do_something.connect(lambda result: print(result))
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not change the default behavior of a built-in function. It will make your code hard to understand and maintain due to hidden logic (why a signal would make a button visible?).

But, you could wrap the connection in a method:

```
class ExampleApp(QWidget):
    def turnOnOption(self, callback):
        """
        Make button visible. Callback will be called when the work is done.
        """
        self.do_something.connect(callback)
        self.button.setVisible(True)

window = ExampleApp()
#window.do_something.connect(lambda result: print(result))
window.turnOnOption(lambda result: print(result))
```

It's explicit for the other developers and your code doesn't look like black magic...